# Alternative proof that all inscribed angles with the same arc are congruent

Tags: euclidean-geometry

There is a classic proof that because two inscribed angles with the same arc share the same central angle that is twice the measure of them both, and by the transitive property the two angles are congruent, but I was wondering if there is a way of proving this without knowing this theorem beforehand.